# how to run main java class with 2 other java classes created using windowbuilder

Tags: java, swing

so i have created 3 GUI using WindowBuilder namely Main_Menu.java and 2 other classes. the other 2 classes also have public static void main(String[] args) in their codes and have 2 buttons that will run the other classes. it works perfectly in the preview but when I turned it into a .jar, DISASTER. :(

so I bet public static void main(String[] args) should only be in the Main_Menu.java. how can I achieve this? any tutorial and tips?

Comment: You would need to identify which class ties everything together and launches the main UI components so that they can, in turn, launch the others.

Comment: for example i have game.java main_menu.java and credits.java when i turned it into a jar file, game.java was the one running instead of main_menu.java

Comment: If it is *just* a matter of different classes being chosen as the starting point, you should be able to modify the main entry point in your application's manifest file.

Comment: where can i locate and edit this manifest file?

Comment: Should be somewhere within your .Jar file (try unzipping it).